# Issue on Webdriver Initialization

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

While running chrome driver, the following error message shows on console repeated.
It won't affect anything. But someone please suggest why it was showing ? how to stop it..

SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```